# How do you access the Google Sheets API via a Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to call the Google Sheets API via a Google Apps Script. As an example, I have followed the instructions provided here:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

I have generated the client ID and API Key via my Google Cloud Platform project as suggested elsewhere.

Now, I have created a google apps script with two files, the Code.gs file and a file called index.html containing the code copied and pasted from the Google Sheets API Quickstart above (with my client ID and API inserted).

When testing deployment, I get the following error message:

```
{
  "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
  "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: https://<some numbers>-script.googleusercontent.com has not been registered for client ID <MY_CLIENT_ID>. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."
}
```

I have registered script.google.com as an origin for my project.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? How would I proceed from here to get past this error?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Did you know that the Google Sheets API is already integrate in Google Apps Script? See the Advanced Services section in Apps Script docs.

Comment: Related to advanced services in Google Apps Script -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/65832570/1595451

Comment: @Rubén I wasn't aware of this. Thank you! Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make use of the `Sheets API` in Apps Script you will have to make use of the Sheets Advanced Service.

For this you will have to go to `Services +` and then add the `Google Sheets API`:

[image: sheets advanced service]

Since this is an advanced service, the authorization flow will be handled by Google so you won't have to provide the `clientId` and the `API key`.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).